# How to vectorize the evaluation of bilinear & quadratic forms?

Tags: python, r, matlab, matrix, numpy

Given any *n* x *n* matrix of real coefficients *A*, we can define a bilinear form *b*<sub>*A*</sub> : *R*<sup>*n*</sup> x *R*<sup>*n*</sup> → *R* by

> *b*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x*, *y*) = *x*<sup>T</sup>*Ay* ,

and a quadratic form *q*<sub>*A*</sub> : *R*<sup>*n*</sup> → *R* by

> *q*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x*) = *b*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x*, *x*) = *x*<sup>T</sup>*Ax* .

(For most common applications of quadratic forms *q<sub>A</sub>*, the matrix *A* is symmetric, or even symmetric positive definite, so feel free to assume that either one of these is the case, if it matters for your answer.)

(Also, FWIW, *b<sub>I</sub>* and *q<sub>I</sub>* (where *I* is the *n* x *n* identity matrix) are, respectively, the standard inner product, and squared *L*<sup>2</sup>-norm on *R<sup>n</sup>*, i.e. *x*<sup>T</sup>*y* and *x*<sup>T</sup>*x*.)

Now suppose I have two *n* x *m* matrices, *X* and *Y*, and an *n* x *n* matrix *A*.  I would like to optimize the computation of both *b*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x<sub>,i</sub>*, *y<sub>,i</sub>*) and *q*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x<sub>,i</sub>*) (where *x<sub>,i</sub>* and *y<sub>,i</sub>* denote the *i*-th column of *X* and *Y*, respectively), and I surmise that, at least in some environments like numpy, R, or Matlab, this will involve some form of vectorization.

The only solution I can think of requires generating diagonal block matrices [*X*], [*Y*] and [*A*], with dimensions *mn* x *m*, *mn* x *m*, and *mn* x *mn*, respectively, and with (block) diagonal elements *x<sub>,i</sub>*, *y<sub>,i</sub>*, and *A*, respectively.  Then the desired computations would be the matrix multiplications [*X*]<sup>T</sup>[*A*][*Y*] and [*X*]<sup>T</sup>[*A*][*X*].  This strategy is most definitely uninspired, but if there is a way to do it that is efficient in terms of both time and space, I'd like to see it.  (It goes without saying that any implementation of it that does not exploit the sparsity of these block matrices would be doomed.)

Is there a better approach?

My preference of system for doing this is numpy, but answers in terms of some other system that supports efficient matrix computations, such as R or Matlab, may be OK too (assuming that I can figure out how to port them to numpy).

Thanks!

<sub>Of course, computing the products *X<sup>T</sup>AY* and *X<sup>T</sup>AX* would compute the desired *b*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x<sub>,i</sub>*, *y<sub>,i</sub>*) and *q*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x<sub>,i</sub>*) (as the diagonal elements of the resulting *m* x *m* matrices), along with the *O*(*m*<sup>2</sup>) irrelevant *b*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x<sub>,i</sub>*, *y<sub>,j</sub>*) and *b*<sub>*A*</sub>(*x<sub>,i</sub>*, *x<sub>,j</sub>*), (for *i* ≠ *j*), so this is a non-starter.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution in numpy that should give you what you're looking for:

```
((np.matrix(X).T*np.matrix(A)).A * Y.T.A).sum(1)
```

This does matrix multiplication for X<sup>T</sup> * A, then does element-by-element array multiplication to multiply by Y<sup>T</sup>. The rows of the resulting array are then summed to yield a 1-D array.

Comment: Thanks!  Did you mean ((np.matrix(X).T*np.matrix(A)).A * **np.matrix(Y)**.T.A).sum(1)?

Comment: If you store X, A and Y as matrices it can be shorter: ((X.T*A).A *Y.T.A).sum(1). I was including the np.matrix calls mainly to clarify matrix multiplication vs element-by-element multiplication.

Comment: or just sticking with arrays: (np.dot(X.T, A) * Y.T).sum(1)

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but in R, you use `crossprod` to form cross-products: given matrices `X` and `Y` with compatible dimensions, `crossprod(X, Y)` returns X<sup>T</sup>Y. Similarly, matrix multiplication is achieved with the `%*%` operator: `X %*% Y` returns the product XY. So you can get X<sup>T</sup>AY as `crossprod(X, A %*% Y)` without having to worry about the mechanics of matrix multiplication, loops, or whatever.

If your matrices have a particular structure that allows optimising the computations (symmetric, triangular, sparse, banded, ...), you could look at the `Matrix` package, which has some support for this.

I haven't used Matlab, but I'm sure it would have similar functions for these operations.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it in MATLAB it is really straightforward:

You can just type

```
b = x'*A*y;
q = x'*A*x;
```

I doubt whether it will be worth the effort, but if you want to speed things up you could try this:

```
M = x'*A;
b = M*y;
q = M*x;
```

Comment: You're not answering this question. If x and y are matrices of column vectors and F is a square matrix, then the correct answer is a vector of values, not a matrix as is your result. I think the correct forumla is `sum((x'*F).*y', 2)`.

Comment: Or even simpler: `sum(x.*(F*y))`

Comment: @peci1 I don't see why the result should be a vector rather than a matrix. The following would make me believe a matrix should be the outcome: "[X], [Y] and [A], with dimensions mn x m, mn x m, and mn x mn, respectively, and with (block) diagonal elements x,i, y,i, and A, respectively. Then the desired computations would be the matrix multiplications [X]T[A][Y] and [X]T[A][X]"

Comment: Just read the first paragraphs of the question. `b_A : R^n x R^n → R` is the bilinear form for a single input vector. The result is just a single real number. So if you put `m` input vectors, the result should just be `m` real numbers.